# Cannot filter Docker service names with underscore

Tags: docker

I'd like to only show Docker services matching a certain name. As I read in the docs I can use the `--filter` option for that. However the result on the command is empty.

```
root@vm-001:~# docker service ls | grep mariadb
dou04akhbm85  develop_mariadb_demo  replicated  1/1  myimage  *:30061->3306/tcp

root@vm-001:~# docker service ls --filter name=mariadb
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
```

When I run `docker service ls --filter name=develop_mariadb` the result is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter syntax for a name matches when a service begins with the same value. So you can run any of the following:

```
docker service ls --filter name=develop_mariadb
docker service ls --filter name=develop_maria
docker service ls --filter name=develop_
docker service ls --filter name=develop
docker service ls --filter name=dev
```

However, the `name=mariadb` will not work since the service name does not begin with that string.

You can see more from this in the following issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37054

Comment: I've submitted a PR on the docs to remove any confusion they create. https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1910